# How to run mysqltuner script on a unix server?

Tags: mysqltuner

Surprisingly I couldn't find a single tutorial for beginner about this script so it's gonna be an ultimate beginner question.

**What I want to do :**

I want to run the mysqltuner script to get information about the configuration of a server. I need a diagnosis as I encounter a few problems with this server and this script seems to be an reliable way to have one.

**What I have :**

- mysqltuner.pl
- the ftp access to the server
- the phpmyadmin access

**Information about the server :**

- Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.20 OpenSSL/0.9.8o
- Version MySQL: 5.0.44

And that's it. I have no idea how to run it. I feel like somehow I should upload it on the server (ftp) and they run it using.. something, but I don't have the knowledge to make use of the information given on the website ( http://mysqltuner.com/ )

**Instruction that makes no sense to me:**

(from mysqltuner.com)
The simplest and shortest method is:

```
wget mysqltuner.pl
perl mysqltuner.pl
```

Of course, you can add the execute bit (chmod +x mysqltuner.pl) so you can execute it without calling perl directly.

**Question** :

With the information I have access to, how to run mysqltuner on this server?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a remote shell or physical access to the server. The ftp user and phpmyadmin isn't useful. The script seems to use only perl but not php whatsoever! Install perl when it's asked.